# Common linear factor of two cubic equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the condition that

> $ax^3+bx+c$ and $tx^3+lx+f$ have a common linear factor

If $x-i$ be the common linear factor then

> $ai^3+bi+c=0$ and $ti^3+li+f=0$

Now eliminating $i$ from both equations we get the required condition.But I am stuck at elimination.

Comment: Do you know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix?